# Expected a dictionary, but got str Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Right now I am creating a user department with a list of users that are a foreign key back to the main user model.  I had this working yesterday, but for some reason I screwed it up.  I imagine it has something to do with the serializers.  I want to be able to post a list of users in this format

```
['jack', 'tom']
```

However, even using the raw data api this is not allowing me to do this.  Here is my code:

Serializers:

```
    class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_department = UserSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Departments
        fields = '__all__'
class DepartmentUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_department = UserSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Departments
        fields = ['department_name', 'department_head', 'user_department']
```

I swear yesterday it was allowing me to select from a list of users in the api.  I could also post and it would work from the front end.  However, now whenever I create a department it's expecting a dictionary, which I am not trying to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the nested serializer you need to **add the nested serializer field** (user_department in your case) to the fields too, as you can see you used

```
fields = '__all__'
```

which does not include your nested serializer field, you need to manually add that to the meta fields

Comment: Whats the difference between using UserSerialzer or UserSeraializer(many=True)?  Does that mean there is a way to inject dictionaries into postgres models?

Comment: It only means that you aren't passing any arguments to the Serializer instance, when you write many=True or read-only=True it only helps you shape your nested Serializer(I think not passing any arguments means it assumes the defaults), I would highly recommend you to follow the DRF documentation, as for your specific issue I think specifying the nested field and passing many=True will work

Comment: Dude I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Dudes, for whatever reason, removing () after the UserSerializer fixed it.  If anyone can explain why that would be even better!

```
    class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_department = UserSerializer
    class Meta:
        model = Departments
        fields =['department_name', 'department_head', 'user_department']
class DepartmentUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_department = UserSerializer
    class Meta:
        model = Departments
        fields = ['department_name', 'department_head', 'user_department']
```

Comment: Keeping open for now

Comment: Did you find any reason for the same?